# Shared archive between Gmail and Outlook

Tags: outlook, gmail, archive

I need to access a Gmail account from both Gmail and Outlook. This seems to generally work OK despite the differences between labels and folders: messages with multiple labels appear in multiple Outlook folders, etc.

The one place I'm having trouble is with archived mail. Messages archived from Gmail have no label, so are not imap'd to Outlook and are not searchable from Outlook.

Is there any way to make this work, or any reasonable workflow workaround?  My goals are:

- Old messages remain searchable, but not in my inbox.
- Single keystroke or mouse click to move a message into this state.
- Searchable from both Gmail's web interface and the Outlook desktop client

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to most of my question on the Superuser Stackoverflow site: https://superuser.com/a/785136/538789 explains how to do almost everything I wanted and https://superuser.com/a/758329/538789 (another answer to the same question) fills in the remaining bit of how to make GMail's archive be searchable from Outlook.

Short answer, in case those links ever die:

- In GMail's IMAP settings: auto-expunge immediate; archive the message.
- In Outlook's settings: In *File -> Account Settings -> Account Settings -> Email Tab -> Select your account -> Change button -> More Settings -> Advanced* Tab: Under **Deleted Items** enable **Mark Items for deletion but do not move them automatically**
- In Outlook: manually create an "All Mail" folder under [Gmail]